# Automated Direct Message Response using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, wrapper, tweepy

I currently am making use of the tweepy package in python for a DM listener. I wish to send a reply to the sender on reception of their message. I have the following:

```
class StdOutListener( StreamListener ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.tweetCount = 0

    def on_connect( self ):
        print("Connection established!!")

    def on_disconnect( self, notice ):
        print("Connection lost!! : ", notice)

    def on_data( self, status ):
        status = str(status)
        try:
            json_acceptable_string = status.replace('\\','')
            #string to dict
            status=json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
            if 'direct_message' in status.keys():
                print '\n'
                print status[u'direct_message'][u'sender_screen_name'] +' sent: '+ status[u'direct_message'][u'text']
                message=str(status[u'direct_message'][u'text'])
                api.send_direct_message(screen_name=str(status[u'direct_message'][u'sender_screen_name']),text='Out of office now - will respond to you asap')
                print 'auto response submitted'
            else:
                #not direct message flow
                pass
        except:
            #not important flows - couldn't convert to json/not correct flow in stream
            pass
        return True

def main():
    global api
    try:
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.secure = True
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api = API(auth)
        print(api.me().name)
        stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())
        stream.userstream()

    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error in main()", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For some reason, I can see the print statement of the user and what they sent but when it gets to the send_direct_message method it hangs. 
Oddly enough, if I message myself, I receive a barrage of messages as it loops. Is this because it's on_data()? How can I make this work for other senders?

**UPDATE**: Resolved - regnerated tokens and add conditional to check for sender, essentially blacklisting myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Resolved - regenerated tokens and add conditional to check for sender, essentially blacklisting myself.

Comment: Thanks. For future readers, remember to enable access to direct messages for your application under the permissions tab. After that regenerate both consumer and access tokens for changes to take effect. Old tokens will result in a 401 error and mere changing them without changing permissions won't work.