# How to use stream to answer twitter DM using tweepy 4.4.0?

Tags: python, streaming, tweepy

I currently have a twitter that's supposed to answer to twitter direct messages, I want to get messages from a stream listener like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984654/automated-direct-message-response-using-tweepy) but tweepy has been updated since the post and the stream listener class doesn't exist anymore.
On [tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/stream.html?highlight=stream) the stream method seems to only be able to track statuses (tweets) and not direct messages. Was this feature remove ? Or is it a different method ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.